# What does this Perl one-line filter do with the fetched XML?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, curl, pipe

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | perl -ne 'print "\t" if //; print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

I understand the first part. It gets the XML using command line arguments for authentification, then passes it to Perl. But what does the Perl bit do? I know it looks for things, but is it a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-n` : wrap the program in `while (<>) { ... }` (e.g. repeat for each line).

`-e` : the following code is the program to be executed.

```
print "\t" if //;  # if the previous regex matches this line, print a tab

print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;
                   # if the current line starts contains
                   # <title>...</title> or <name>...</name>,
                   # print the bit between the tags, and a newline
```

I'm not sure that this program does anything useful, perhaps there was an error in transcription.  Where did you get the code from and what is it meant to do?

Comment: also - how would i get it to *not* display a certain XML tag

Answer (score 1):

```
print "\t" if //;
print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;
```

Yes it's regex, the `//` and `/<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/` are regex matchers.  I don't know perl so I'm not sure what the first is for (maybe prints a tab for blank lines), but the second finds any `<title>` or `<name>` elements and extracts the content and then I assume prints it.